# WinUI - Dependency Injection and Window Navigation

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, navigation, winui-3

I am trying to understand how to properly use dependency injection for Navigating to different pages on my application. Currently just a Main Window & a Login Window. Now that I have my Windows stored in the `NavigationService._windows`, how do I create / access an instance of that window?

Thanks for your help.

This is the relevant code in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
    protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Container = RegisterServices();

        _loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
        _loginWindow.Activate();
    }

    private IServiceProvider RegisterServices()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        var navigationService = new NavigationService();

        // Register Windows:
        navigationService.Configure(nameof(LoginWindow), typeof(LoginWindow));
        navigationService.Configure(nameof(MainWindow), typeof(MainWindow));

        services.AddSingleton<INavigationService>(navigationService);

        // Register ViewModels:
        services.AddTransient<LoginViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

Here is my `NavigationService` class where the two windows are registered into:

```
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, Type> _windows = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type>();
    // Interface Implementation
    public string CurrentWindow => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public void GoBack()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void NavigateTo(string window, object parameter = null)
    {
        if (!_windows.ContainsKey(window))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Unable to find a page registered with the name {window}.");
        }

        // Code to navigate to window should go here...
        // this is where I'm a bit stuck.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // Class Functions:
    public void Configure(string window, Type type)
    {
        if (_windows.Values.Any(v => v == type))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The {type.Name} view has already been registered under another name.");
        }

        _windows[window] = type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear from the code you supplied how you're trying to use DI in your application. But here's an approach I've been using:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public new static App Current => (App)Application.Current;

    public IJ4JHost Host { get; }

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var hostConfig = new J4JHostConfiguration()
                        .Publisher( "J4JSoftware" )
                        .ApplicationName( "GPSLocator" )
                        .LoggerInitializer( InitializeLogger )
                        .AddNetEventSinkToLogger()
                        .AddDependencyInjectionInitializers( SetupDependencyInjection )
                        .AddServicesInitializers( InitializeServices )
                        .AddUserConfigurationFile( "userConfig.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true )
                        .AddApplicationConfigurationFile( "appConfig.json", optional: false )
                        .FilePathTrimmer( FilePathTrimmer );

        if (hostConfig.MissingRequirements != J4JHostRequirements.AllMet)
            throw new ApplicationException($"Missing J4JHostConfiguration items: {hostConfig.MissingRequirements}");

        Host = hostConfig.Build()
         ?? throw new NullReferenceException($"Failed to build {nameof(IJ4JHost)}");
    }
}
```

Without going into the details of how my host configuration builder works, basically it has a DI setup component (along with a bunch of other stuff, like logging and command line processing) which you can access via a `Services` property exposed on `IJ4JHost`.

This setup essentially makes the `App` class the viewmodel locator, if that term means anything to you.

For example, if I need an instance of a particular viewmodel someplace I would get it like this:

```cs
Configuration = App.Current.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<AppConfig>();
```

If you want to see more details on how my host builder works you can check out its [github repository](https://github.com/markolbert/ProgrammingUtilities). It's located in the DependencyInjection project folder.

You can see examples of how I use this in action at a [github repository for a GPS locator app](https://github.com/markolbert/GPSLocator) I'm writing.